# SQL server management studio 2005: Still can't copy column headers(checked option to include it already)!

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, headers, ssms

I already changed the option to include column headers(Tools->option->results to grid->include column headers). Yet if I copy paste a Table or SQL query grid data results into Excel, i don't export the column names. How do I get column names to be simply copied from SQL table to Excel? I am new to SSMS and this is driving me crazy. What does it mean when it says changes will take effect in new window or something. What does it mean? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The option will not be set for existing query windows.  It only gets applied to new query windows that are created after the option is set.